# Review on Smartphone

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am wondering if it is possible to review posts on your smartphone? I know that this may seem like a rather unimportant question, but when I  am using my Stackexchange app I am not able to find the review section. 
I am commuting to work everyday by train and sometimes I would like to use this time to do some reviews, etc.
Why is this feature disabled in the smartphone version?

Comment: See [Are review queues available from the Android app?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246206/164403) and [Are the review queues planned for the iOS app?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231492/164403) on the Overmeta.

Comment: This *must* use the Tinder interface if it's ever implemented! Swipe left, swipe right... :o)